# How to load json data inside Jquery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I am working on Jquery Mobile and I want to get Json data inside list view as shown in this link **[ListView](http://api.jquerymobile.com/resources/listview/example12.html)** . I already tried using Jquery and Ajax it's success. but coming to Jquery Mobile data is not loading. why?

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/madhu72kumar/QZ342/4/)**

```
//code
var content='';     
      $.each(data,function(index,item){            
            content +=  '<img src="'+item.thumb+'"  class="userimage">';
            content +=  '<h3 class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</h3>';                  
            content +='<p class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</p>';    
            });
      $('#ball').append(content);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QZ342/9/

#### HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page" id="index" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active">
            <div data-role="content" class="ui-content"> 
                <ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" id="ball">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://www.myappdemo.net/dev_bloopit/index.php/bloopit/Bloops?userid=145&category=popular&start=0",function(data){        
        var content='';     
        $.each(data,function(index,item){     
            content +=  '<li><a href="index.html"><img src="'+item.thumb+'"  class="userimage">';
            content +=  '<h3 class="userurl">'+item.keywords+'</h3>';                  
            content +='<p class="username">'+item.bombscount+'</p></a></li>';    
        });
        $('#ball').append(content);        
        $('#ball').listview('refresh');
    });
});
```

### Changes:

- document ready was not properly closed
- one time note, don't use document ready with jQuery Mobile, use pageinit event, but this is beside the point
- listview was created incorrectly so I have fixed the layout
- listview was not enhanced after content was appended

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to close your document ready function.

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yzj46/)

```
});
```

Comment: +1 for actually spotting, and explaining, the *real* problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing quote(') on this line:

```
content +=  '<img src="'+item.thumb+'"  class="userimage">;
```